# Should I change all formats when I get contacts?

Tags: swift, contacts

I used CNContact to get phone numbers.

```
contact.phoneNumbers[0].value.stringValue
```

I want to this formating like '010-1111-2222'

but all formats are different like below

010-1111-2222

01011112222

+821011112222

//01011112222

1011112222

010 11 112 22 2

Should I consider changing all the formats?

or is there another option to choose from?

Comment: Just removing all character except number then reformat.

Comment: https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit